# Downloaded a open source program, but cant find the design

Tags: c#, open-source

I am very new to this. But I have made some simple programs before.

I would like to use a open source project to make my own smaller version. It also help me understand what does what and why.

So, this is where I got the open source....
https://github.com/mikebb203/IPC-Hammer

The problem is when I open it up in Visual Studios 2015, I cant find the design, or even how to open it. Which I really do need. When I click on the button it brings me to the code then helps me understand what's happening.

How do I open the design to view the program design?
Thank you in advance :)

I down loaded the open source, but the design is missing. I would like to be able to open the design to help me understand the coding better.

Comment: Maybe you need to have a .NetFramework version 4.6.1.

Comment: At least one of the projects targets .Net Standard 2.0 which VS 2015 _absolutely_ does not support. Consider using the newest version of Visual Studio - VS 2022.

Comment: Could someone else download this and see if it views on their newer version?

Comment: LOL no   https://github.com/mikebb203/IPC-Hammer/blob/master/IPCHammer/IpcHammer.csproj#L11